# Solving Server Time Out?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

When I try to run my jsp file i am getting this error. ..in the console it is displayed as server stated but it is not actually...finally i am getting error as server timeout...Help me...Thank u!!!
NOTE:I am using tomcat server 7.0

```
Jul 17, 2014 8:38:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Sony\VAIO Improvement\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;.
Jul 17, 2014 8:38:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Demo' did not find a matching property.
Jul 17, 2014 8:38:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 17, 2014 8:38:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 17, 2014 8:38:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1155 ms
Jul 17, 2014 8:38:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 17, 2014 8:38:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Jul 17, 2014 8:38:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 17, 2014 8:38:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 17, 2014 8:38:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 883 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

This warning is screaming about not having PropertyRules set.

The solution to this problem is very simple. Double click on your tomcat server. It will open the server configuration. Under server options check ‘Publish module contents to separate XML files’ checkbox. Restart your server. This time your page will come without any issues.